# What is wrong with this script to create files in all subfolders?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a directory tree, consisting of several layers, within which I want to create 30 placeholder files, recursively in each folder.

The tree looks something like this:

```
--F:\inbox\test  
 ----folder1  
 ------subfolder1  
 ------subfolder2  
 ----folder2  
 ------subfolder1  
 ------subfolder2  
 ----folder3  
 ------subfolder1  
 ------subfolder2
```

Here is what I have.

```
$folders = gci -path f:\inbox\test -recurse | where {$_.PsIsContainer}  
foreach ($folder in $folders) {  
        1..30 | % { New-Item -Name "$_.txt" -Value (get-date).tostring() -Itemtype file -force}
}
```

This just creates 30 files in the root folder. I know I am missing something in my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not telling `new-item` where to put the file, so it uses the current working directory. Fortunately, this is easliy fixed with the `-Path` parameter for the cmdlet.

```
$folders = gci -path f:\inbox\test -recurse | where {$_.PsIsContainer}  
foreach ($folder in $folders) {  
        1..30 | % { New-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Name "$_.txt" -Value (get-date).tostring() -Itemtype file -force}
}
```

Comment: Smashing. I see my error. I mistakenly thought the `new-item` would execute within the `$folder`, as the script looped through. Thank you for clearing that up.

Comment: Unless you're explicitly calling `set-location`, assume that you're not changing your working directory. And even if you do that, being very explicit about what operation you're performing on what path is usually a good decision (even if it seems redundant sometimes) for future maintainability and reduction in bugs.