# What is wrong with my script? Deletes all files -- Powershell

Tags: powershell-2.0

I want to delete files recursively, while keeping the seven most recent ones. The following script deletes all files, even though I specify the `skip` parameter.

`$files = gci -path f:\inbox\test -recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}

foreach ($file in $files) {sort creationtime -desc | select -skip 7 | remove-item -path $file.FullName -force}`

This script doesn't do a damn thing:

`gci -path f:\inbox\test -recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | foreach-object {sort creationtime -desc | select -skip 7 | remove-item -force }`

Comment: Seems like you should be skippping earlier in the chain. Within the foreach you'd only be working on a single filename at a time, so there's no 7 to skip.

Comment: /facepalm. I see that now. Thank you for pointing it out. Scripting and me, not so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$files = gci -path f:\inbox\test -recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | sort creationtime -desc | select -skip 7 

foreach ($file in $files) {remove-item -path $file.FullName -force}
```

or more simply

```
gci -path f:\inbox\test -recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer} | sort creationtime -desc |
select -skip 7 | remove-item -force
```

Comment: This partially worked. It saved the seven most recent files in the last directory of my tree. Under `f:\inbox\test`, I have four directories. Each of those has five directories. The only directory that has seven files is `f:\inbox\test\dir4\dir5`. Prior to running the delete, all directories have 30 files. All created with a script. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911435/what-is-wrong-with-this-script-to-create-files-in-all-subfolders) is what I am using to create the files. I need to look into this further. Must be something with the file creation. Cheers.